# How to create equations with a module with variables and then pass them to another module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I want to solve a non-linear system using `root` from scipy. I generated the equations with loops. Every time the solver iterates to find the solutions all the loops that generate the equations run again, which slow the solution time. I want to create a code that generate the equations only once and then with the generated equations solve the system.

For example, the following loop is in the code. For every iteration it generates the equations again. I want to generate the equations once and then solve the system with root, not generate the equation over and over again on every iteration of the solver.

```py
def Colebrook(R,Re,d,f):
    F =  (-2.0*np.log10((R/(3.7*d) + (2.51/(Re*(np.sqrt(f)))))) - 1.0/(np.sqrt(f)))
    return F

def ec(y):
    if usar_darcy ==True:
        for i in range(len(n)):
            for a in range(len(n[i])):
                for b in range(n[i][a]):
                    if y[Cont_col+Cont_cau]>=2000 and usar_darcy == True:
                        col = Colebrook(Rl,y[Cont_col+Cont_cau],Dl,
                                    y[Cont_col + Cont_cau + Contador_re])
                        colebrook2.append(col)
                    if y[Cont_col+Cont_cau]<=2000 and usar_darcy == True:
                        col = Laminar2(y[Cont_col+Cont_cau],
                                   y[Cont_col + Cont_cau + Contador_re])
                        colebrook2.append(col)
                    Cont_col = Cont_col + 1
    return list_with_all_The_equations

def solver():
    sol = root(ec, Guess,method='hybr', jac=False)    
    print(sol)

    return sol

solver()
```

Comment: Where are you actually calling the `ec()` method? and what does it return? the code in question seems incomplete.

Comment: I think you may have said the operative word, *generate*. Your code is difficult to follow, but I suspect you want to create a generator function that yields successive equations.

Comment: i want to generate the equations only one time with a method and then solve the already generated equations with other. the problem is that the equations in the first method have unkonws so if i call ec() it will send an error. i want to optimize the code because everytime that the solver iterates to find the solution it generate the equations with the loops and then iterates.

Comment: Maybe sympy could be used to generate the functions? Followed by substituting the real variables and maybe lambdify to create a numpy function?

Comment: Can you add some examples of equations? What does `Colebrook` do?  It is hard to understand what you mean.

Comment: The code looks much more complex than needed.  You have three loops, over `i`, `a` and `b`, and it seems the only thing they do is move an index into `y`. Better to make `y` a real matrix.  You also should try to rewrite your code with much less global variables.